# After installing 16.04 LTS, I can't log in

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've been using 15.10 for quite some time and I updated to 16.04. I did a complete reinstall. After the installation was completed, I logged in, downloaded a few apps, set the nvidia driver and rebooted. After the reboot, I tried to log in and it threw me back to the greeting screen. I purged all nvidia related stuff from tty1 and set nouveau back but nothing changed.
I reinstalled the whole thing again with the same results.

I'm out of ideas. :/

You can see the same thing happening on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrgPYvoVJfA this video.

Thanks!

Edit: Also worth noting, every time I installed it, it killed the live USB. I had to reload the image on it because it gave me a kernel panic after I tried to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I watched the video."also my English is very very very very bad."
It didn't happened to me before.I think theres a problem with the desktop.
But you could try these:

*Delete Ubuntu and download "16.04" again
**Or Delete Ubuntu and download "15.10" than upgrade it.
***Or Replace Ubuntu "16.04" with yours on the "installation cd/usb"
or

*When you're on the screen "Ctrl+Alt+F1" and type "sudo apt-get install unity"

I took this from SiddharthaRT this solution worked for many people

---

Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login into the shell.

Now run ls -lah. If in the output the line

-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority

then you need to do chown username:username .Xauthority and try logging in.

Else, do ls -ld /tmp. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: drwxrwxrwt.

drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp

Else, you need to do sudo chmod a+wt /tmp and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

1. dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

   2. or uninstall, reinstall it.

Now press Alt+-> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.

Comment: I hope this works for you :).

Comment: Reinstalled it again, without ever trying to use nvidia drivers and now it's working.

The problem is probably with nvidia but I have no idea what should I do about it. There is heavy flickering with nouveau drivers which is very annoying after a few hours of work.

I have an ASUS UX303LB with GT940M.

Comment: So I'm happy you solved it. :3 I think Nvidia doesn't support Ubuntu 16.04.I also never tried downloading nvidia drivers :D.